# why results of function save late?

Tags: database, postgresql, function, view

today i faced with a strange problem. i want to invoke a plpgsql function inside a view(i know it is  a bad and strange way to call a function so please don't mention it in your answers). i do that but the results of function apply after showing the results of view!!!

i want to know how it is possible? and how i can force pgpgsql function to store its result before finishing the query?

some information about my code:

plan: this is a table about travel plans including date_of_travel, price etc.

travel_check(): this is a function that deletes those records from plan table that their date_of_travel is less than current_date and store them to another table and return an integer.(this is not important so much just remember this function delete some records from plan table) but i write exact definition below:

```
    create or replace function finish_travel(todelete integer) returns void as
        $body$
        begin
            create table if not exists history_of_travel(
                id integer,
                traveldate date,
                source_id char(3),
                destination_id char(3),
                timeofday time
            );
            insert into history_of_travel
              select id,traveldate,source_id,destination_id,timeofday
              from plan
              where id=todelete;
            delete from plan where id=todelete;
        end;
        $body$
        language plpgsql volatile;


        create or replace function travel_check() returns int as
        $body$
        declare
          trip record;
        begin
            for trip in select *
                          from plan
            loop
                if(trip.traveldate<current_date) then
                    perform finish_travel(trip.id);
                end if;
                if(trip.traveldate=current_date and trip.timeofday=now()::timestamp(0)::time) then
                    perform finish_travel(trip.id);
                end if;
            end loop;
            return 1;
        end;
        $body$
        language plpgsql volatile;
```

i want to create a view containing two step:

1. call function and update plan.
2. show the plan's records.

i tried below code

```
           create view clients_select_query as
                       select plan.*
                       from plan,(select travel_check()) as d
                        where exists(select * from plan)
```

when i run:

```
    select * from  clients_select_query
```

unfortunately it shows the contents of plan table without any change

but if i run again:

```
    select * from  clients_select_query
```

or

```
    select * from plan
```

i see that the changes have been applied.

how i can see changes after first running query without changing method?

if it's not clear, tell me to put exact definition of function,table and view

Comment: I think we'll need your function's code to understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ Arkhena, i edited my question.

thank you for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result isn't "saved late", but Postgres hides the changes from you, so that queries behave predictably.

Postgres' [concurrency control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) means that a query won't see any changes after it started running. This is true even if your own query is making the changes, and there is no way to avoid it.

Instead, you could create a set-returning function which does the deletion first, and then returns the contents of the table using a second query. Then, create a view which selects from that function.

```
create function clients_select_function() returns setof plan as $$
  select travel_check();
  select * from plan;
$$
language sql;

create view clients_select_query as
  select * from clients_select_function();
```

Comment: thank you so much, that is exact reason of problem and a good solution for it

it works fine.